# Check out From SVN in Maven Module Project Using cmd

Tags: svn, maven

I have a Maven Mutil Module Project in SVN.

I want to build it using command. But I got the Exception of `"Child Module does not exist."`

I just want to checkout all the code and then build them by `"mvn clean install."`

If I build the project under the workspace of the project, it would be built as what I wished.

Could anyone help me? 
Many Thanks in Advance.

Here are some images:

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M04Wj.jpg)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsd9i.jpg)

Comment: That sounds like a chicken and egg problem. You would like to checkout via Maven a project which needs a pom which is correct. In your case it's not cause you have submodules which do not exist. So Maven can't parse it correctly (which is not surprising). Why not using the VCS for that? What's the intention? And what would be the advantage of that?